# To pass the Response from the nested function `Django REST framework`

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using python django with `Django REST framework`

It can return the Reponse to the browser like this, in the `views.py`

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
    @api_view(['GET'])
    def get_by(request):
        res = {"test":"answer"}
        return Response(res)
```

I want to pass the Response to the browser where nested function

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
    @api_view(['GET'])
    def get_by(request):
        x(t)

def x():
   #error happens here!!
    res = {"error":"error happens!!"}
    return Response(res)
```

in this case, it is simple, I can return the error to the first function and first function can return the error Response.

but when you have three four,five nested function?

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the previous answer you can use a custom `APIException` inside the function to stop the api handler midway. If you dont want it to return like a system error, you can set the response status code like the example below:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException
from rest_framework import status

class OkException(APIException):
    status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK
    default_detail = "error happens!!"
    default_code = "error_happens"
```

You can then raise it inside the function like a normal exception

```
raise OkException()
```

Answer (score 1):

It should better use serializer or services and handle some validation on that.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation

On the other side, you can develop some customized APIExcepetion and just raised them.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#api-reference

Comment: Thank you very much, but my explanation is not good. I want to show the message to the user in shorthand. error means just like the quiz fail not the system error.